# Statistical Data and Metadata eXchange (SDMX)

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, schema, sdmx

I stuck myself in [SDMX](http://sdmx.org/), Since i am not found enough resources to study(programming code) about SDMX.

Like:-

```
 Creating structure
 Reading Structure
 Writing data .. etc
```

Yes there are some guideline in its [personal website](http://sdmx.org/?page_id=11),But those are not enough to start ride on sdmx.
So its my personal request to all u my friends if you have any experience please share.

Any help will appreciated

Comment: Have you read through http://sdmx.org/?page_id=38 ?

Comment: @MarcusRickert!! would you think this page has enough information for the biggner. friend, i already read this page ,But i am not satisfy enough from this page

Comment: @MarcusRickert will you have any experience how to create SDMX-ML from excel file

Comment: Any one have experience ...?

Answer (score 1):

Here are few links about the topic:

- https://sdmx.org/ (Official page)
- https://sdmx.org/?page_id=2555 (Learning)
- https://sdmx.org/?page_id=4500 (Tools)
- http://www.metadatatechnology.com/sdmx.php#data-format (Tutorial)
- https://www.oecd.org/statistics/data-collection/How%20to%20report%20FDI%20data%20to%20the%20OECD%20using%20SDMX.pdf
- https://sdmx.org/wp-content/uploads/sdmx-json-data-message.pdf
- https://github.com/sdmx-twg/sdmx-json
- https://github.com/sdmx-twg/sdmx-json/wiki

Quick json format overview (xml is similar):

```
{   
         "header": { ... },
         Header is for technical information: prepared, sender, ...

         "errors": { ... },
         Errors is for error messages.

         "structure": { ... },
         Structure contains metadata: dimensions and attributes.

         "dataSets": [ ... ]
         DataSets contains the actual data.
 }
```

NOTE: In an effort to document it I also created the `sdmx` stackoverflow tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [SDMX Guidelines for the use of webservices](http://sdmx.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/SDMX_2_1-SECTION_07_WebServicesGuidelines_2013-04.pdf) helpful to get started. The Annex (chapter 6) lists some examples.

Another source of information is on the Eurostat website where you can find a documentation of their [SDMX webservices](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/sdmx_web_services/getting_started/supported_operations).

They also have a [portal site](https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fpfis/mwikis/sdmx/index.php/Main_Page) that provides tutorials on SDMX.

Hope that gets you started.